# Files Not Downloading to Correct Path: Pyrebase4

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I am using firebase storage to try and store user profile pictures. I am then downloading them from the database to my static/uploads folder, like in many flask examples, then using that to display a user's profile picture. I am using pyrebase 4 to download the picture from my firebase storage; however, whenever I try to download it, the file goes it the '/' path instead of my 'static/uploads folder'. I am specifying how to download it like this
`storage.child(user + "/profilepicture.png").download(path="/static/uploads", filename=user + ".png")`

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, shouldn't it be going to the path I specified? The pyrebase documentation doesn't tell you how to specify the path. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Hello! Could you please add some examples of what you are trying to do? You can also help yourself by following the guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and find that i need to add the path with the image name as image name parameter and also add path parameter, Like this

```
storage.child("toPrint/"+imageName).download(IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_PATH,IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_PATH+downloadedImageName+".jpg")
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#download) is not up-to-date for now and if you used the same code you will get an error because you need to add path parameter, Check this [github issue](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4/issues/7)